# Python cannot read full bzip2 file

Tags: python-2.7, file, input, file-io, bzip2

I have a 5.8GB text file compressed in bz2 and I want to count its lines using the following simple script:

```
import bz2
import sys
import logging


inputfile = sys.argv[1]
tot_lines = 0
try:
    bz_file = bz2.BZ2File(inputfile, "r")
    for line in bz_file.readlines():
        tot_lines += 1
except IOError as ioe:
    logging.error("Failed to read latest probes file. Error message: %s" % str(ioe))

print tot_lines # Prints 333
```

The output of the above script is 333 which is apparently wrong. When I run the command below from Ubuntu command-line:

```
$ bzcat inputfile | wc -l
$ 33181407
```

I printed the line where the Python script ends and it's incomplete but doesn't appear to have any special character at the point where it breaks.
There's no error that indicates that the something failed, can it be a decompression error?

Comment: have you tried opening the file in `rt` mode? Also don't use `for line in bz_file.readlines():` just do `for line in bz_file:` you'll save memory

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre when I use `rt` mode I get `ValueError: invalid mode char t`

Comment: @Vasilis Try using bz2.open(<filename>, 'rt') rather than bz2.BZ2File(<filename>, 'rt').